# UDK Cinematics Creation

Tags: animation, 3d, modeling, editing, unreal-development-kit

Can I create very detailed animations within UDK, like samaratian UDK demo, wtihin 3 months?

I don't have any previous experience in UDK, but I modeled something basic models in Zbrush and in 3Ds Max.

So, could I create a fully deatiled and edited animation (of course, first learn it) in 3 months and how much time would I have to invest?

If you have any better program just for 3D cinematic animations scenes, could you put the name of that program and reccomend it for me?

Could you put up some references about UDK (or your progam), so I can start learning right away?

So I am a complete begginer, which main goal is to create detailed animations (I would of course edit the raw 3D animation in video editing program).

Comment: Adobe AfterEffects is a very popular professional package.  Blender is great for 3D modelling and okay for animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create detailed animations using UDK. It is not a animation suite. It is a game engine. What you have to do is make all the animations from another tool such as Maya or 3Ds Max and import them in to UDK.  When you have the right animations in .fbx format you can manipulate them with UDK. You can make animtrees with set of seperate animations. UDK supports features such as blending between animations. Of course you can do a cinematic demo like samaritan , but you need to create animation from another software and import them to UDK. After that using UDK's tools such as Kismet and Matinee you can do the cinematic stuff.